# Liferay - Get default language (locale) for a site

Tags: liferay, locale, default, liferay-6

I need to programmatically get the default locale for a site. So I:

- creata a new site with default language set to english (en_us)
- create a second site with default languge set to german (de_DE)

In my code I've tried to do the following:

```
CompanyThreadLocal.setCompanyId(portletDataContext.getCompanyId());
final Locale locale = LocaleUtil.getDefault();
```

But I get "en_us" for both sites, which is the portal default locale.

I need this in my export/import functions of my `PortletDataHandler` implementation. Otherwise I will allways export my data with the wrong default language from staging to live.

I'm running Liferay 6.1.20 EE.

Thanks in advance, Fabi

Comment: when you mean site is it Liferay's sites in same portal instance or do you mean different portal instances altogether?

Comment: In control panel, I opened the portlet "sites" and added the two sites mentioned in the question.I think they were called `communities` in Liferay 5. So they are in the same portal instance, I guess. You can tell them apart by their `groupId`.

Comment: And how did you set Locale for the Site from Control Panel? The reason I am asking is because I am not seeing a way to associate locale to Site from control panel in Liferay 6.1. I see I can set locale for a portal instance

Comment: It was my fault. I'm using a custom template for the site which has a tab to set the default language. The solution to my problem was to get the language from this template.

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay 6.2 you can just do:

```
Locale defaultLocale = PortalUtil.getSiteDefaultLocale(groupId);
```